# SSRS Parent Column Background Color same as Details Row

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report with one parent group and an expandable details group. My issue is that I would like the parent cell to have the same background color as that of the details row if any of the details rows has color.

For example:
If I have a parent group of PART ID and details rows that contain columns for location and qty. If any of the qtys are below zero then I have a background color expression to set the qty field for that row to a background color of RED. I need the parent PART ID to also be red if any of the details rows are red.

I can't seem to find a solution to this issue on the web and everything I search only seems to return results about background colors for alternating columns which is not at all what I need. Your assistance is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

There's not any kind of function for this. You would need logic based on how your data and report work. Maybe something like:

```
=IIF(SUM(IIF(FIELDS!QTY.VALUE < 0, 1, 0)) > 0, "RED", "WHITE")
```

If any of the QTYs are less than 0, then Red ELSE White.

Comment: I should add that my qty column is a lookup with a running total within so I believe I'll need to use ReportItems!Textbox#.Value. I didn't want to over-complicate the post if it was not needed. When I try to apply the above expression I receive "The BackgroundColor expression for the text box 'Textbox4' uses an aggregate function on a report item.  Aggregate functions can be used only on report items contained in page headers and footers." Trying expression =IIF(SUM(IIF(ReportItems!Textbox32.VALUE < 0, 1, 0) > 0, "RED", "WHITE")

Comment: Hannover Fist: Just to clarify. I think it works but the expression has  a missing close parenthesis for the SUM function.

Comment: Still does not work for me. Am I attempting the impossible? 

The expression for my QTY column is =Lookup(Fields!PART_ID.value,Fields!PART_ID.value,Fields!QTY_AVAILABLE_MRP.value,"DataSet2")+RunningValue(Fields!REQUIRED_QTY.value,sum,"DataSet1")

With a background expression for the QTY column as 
=IIF((Lookup(Fields!PART_ID.value,Fields!PART_ID.value,Fields!QTY_AVAILABLE_MRP.value,"DataSet2")+RunningValue(Fields!REQUIRED_QTY.value,sum,"DataSet1")<0),"Red","White")

I am still receiving the aggregate expression error on Textbox4 which is the PART ID I am trying to show as Red